# Finding an element using selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find the value count of reviews in the below html section, but I am unable to do so , have tried using class name, css selector etc, but it is unable to fid the element. Any help would be appreciated, below is the html section. I also have multiple such elements I ave to loop through and get the review counts, how do I do it?

```
<a class="reviewsCount ml-5 fleft blue-text " href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews/larsen-and-toubro-infotech-reviews?utm_campaign=srp_ratings&amp;utm_medium=desktop&amp;utm_source=naukri" target="_blank" title="Powered by Ambition Box">(2148 Reviews)</a>

<a class="reviewsCount ml-5 fleft blue-text " href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews/dxc-technology-reviews?utm_campaign=srp_ratings&amp;utm_medium=desktop&amp;utm_source=naukri" target="_blank" title="Powered by Ambition Box">(3919 Reviews)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element text with this:

```
all_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews/larsen-and-toubro-infotech-reviews')]").text
```

Now you can extract the count of reviews with this:

```
reviews = int(filter(str.isdigit, all_text))
```

Or with this:

```
import re

reviews = re.findall('\d+', all_text)
```

Don't forget wait / delay before accessing the element to make sure it is fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can mix BeautifulSoap with selenium,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<a class="reviewsCount ml-5 fleft blue-text " href="https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews/larsen-and-toubro-infotech-reviews?utm_campaign=srp_ratings&amp;utm_medium=desktop&amp;utm_source=naukri" target="_blank" title="Powered by Ambition Box">(2148 Reviews)</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
finds = soup.find('a', {'class': 'reviewsCount'})
print(finds.text)
```

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your responses, they work fine when I just have one such element, but what if I have multiple review counts to fetch?

Comment: if you wan to find multiple just use `find_all`, this will give you a list `finds = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'reviewsCount'})`

Answer (score 0):

try with `css selector` :

```
a[href*='https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews/larsen-and-toubro-infotech-reviews'][class^='reviewsCount']
```

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
total_review_count = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='https://www.ambitionbox.com/reviews/larsen-and-toubro-infotech-reviews'][class^='reviewsCount']")))
print(total_review_count.text)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: How this will give you the count??? It seems `total_review_count` is an element it should be  `print(total_review_count.text)`